# How to Subtract 119 days from current date in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, datediff, dateadd

I want to subtract 119 days from given date,

i tried dateadd function but it is not working.

**select dateadd(dd,-119,'09/05/2017')**

Comment: How have you tried it? Showing us code helps us help you.

Comment: Could you let us know what you tried that "is not working"? Otherwise I'm assuming that you wrote something like this `SELECT 119-dateadd-datediff-Yoda = CurrentDate?` :)

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2017-01-01','2017-02-05') AS DiffDate more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: These are basics in sql server just go through the net before asking you have to  adopt how to search through the inernet relavent to your requirement

Comment: I have serched on net as well if you know the answer then say..dont give advice

Comment: @Neha - comments on StackOverflow are *specifically* not for answering the question. You should probably [*familiarize* yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with this site and not expect everyone to change how they interact here to how *you* want them to act.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever...i think rules are applied on everyone.

Comment: @Neha Your asking answer from the members Dont you think it's an advice

Answer (score 1):

`DATEADD` is correct - I don't know how you have used it, but this would be the way:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, -119, @givenDate)
```

Comment: i have used in same manner as you say..but it doesnot give the correct answer..You can also try

Comment: select dateadd(dd,-119,'09/05/2017')

Comment: @Neha - does that mean September fifth or May ninth? You should be using a date format that is not ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Just saying "it is not working" doesn't help. From what I gather, it does work, but you don't know the syntax. Try this -

```
SELECT dateadd(d,-119,getdate())
```

Comment: I tried this as well

Comment: select dateadd(dd,-119,'09/05/2017')

Comment: Change that to '09-05-2017'

Comment: Or even better `20170509` to remove all potential ambiguities.

Comment: @iamdave - `20170509` would remove ambiguities. On older SQL Servers (pre 2008, IIRC), the dashed version can sometimes be interpreted as `yyyy-dd-mm`. Dashes would be correct if you're *also* specifying a time component and separate date and time with `T` (rather than space)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  Noted :)